# Unable to get Long type of data using Dapper

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle, dapper

**The problem:**
I am unable to retrieve a column of type Long in an Oracle DB source and set it to a string property in a class in .Net

**Details:**
While trying to use dapper to fire SQL queries and get back results, I came across a rather weird situation. I cannot share the actual class details, but here is a sample. I have a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string VeryLongMessage { get; set; }
}
```

I fire a dapper query as shown below:

```
using (var con = ConnectionUtility.GetConnection("MyConnectionString"))
{
    var result = con.QueryAsync<MyClass>("SELECT VeryLongMessage FROM MyView");
}
```

But when I check the value in result, I get a null value inside result's VeryLongMessage property.

Has anyone else seen such an issue? Any thoughts or suggestions?

**Things I have verified:**
The column name of my dapper query and the property both match. the property type is string and column in Oracle db's view is Long.

Let me know in case you need more details.

Comment: Is it a LONG or LONG RAW?

Comment: Could it be that you are assigning binary data to a string? Is you make VerLongMessage a byte array does it help?

Comment: @Nishmaster, The column is LONG I believe.

Comment: @JD. The column contains string data and I tried using byte[], but that didnt help.

Comment: If you've created a table with a LONG column, change the column type to LOB. LONG has been deprecated for years, and in fact Oracle's [documentation on the LONG datatype](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00201) explicitly says, "Do not create tables with LONG columns". Share and enjoy.

Comment: @BobJarvis, my database is legacy :) so cant change that :( I'll check once with my DB team, but I think we cant change that. Any other thoughts?

Comment: [This might be of help](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e17732/featData.htm#ODPNT283). Click on the link that says ["Obtaining LONG and LONG RAW Data"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e17732/featData.htm#ODPNT289). Share and enjoy.

Comment: Hey @BobJarvis, Thanks for your help! How can I set this property(InitialLONGFetchSize) in dapper? I am not using a command object...as you can see from my question. I can not select RowId because it would throw an error, and none of my view's selects are unique. Totally lost here (sigh)

Comment: Anybody else? Any thoughts here?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [dapper issue 173](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/issues/detail?id=173)

Unfortunately, it seems there are four indirect ways:

- fix database (in your case you cannot)
- add additional stored finction to fetch LONG as CLOB. Read [Long to Varchar2 conversion..](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:839298816582) and find similar topics on [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:1:0%3a%3aNO)
- fix the dapper :)
- use ADO.NET instead

Comment: Hey Naeel. Thanks for your reply. Looks like I'd have to strike out all the options you suggested :( I want to use Dapper/any settings in Dapper to achieve this.